# Excel Columns Comparison in Generic way and highlight the differences with some color

Tags: python, excel, xlsx, xlsxwriter

I am trying to convert a csv file to excel as per below code and i have few columns which need to be compared inside excel and do conditional format

In the below code i have hard coded cells  "B2<>C2" , "C2:C1048576". Without providing B2,C2 can i make those cells name to read in generic way and compare the complete data in excel

Wherever i have _SRC & _TGT those columns need to be compared simultaneously. Below link has both the sample excels

```
for csvfile in glob.glob(os.path.join('.', "file1.csv")):
    workbook = Workbook(csvfile[:-4] + '.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
    with open(csvfile, 'rt', encoding='utf8') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for r, row in enumerate(reader):
            for c, col in enumerate(row):
                worksheet.write(r, c, col)
    orange_format = workbook.add_format({'bg_color':   '#FFEB9C',
                                     'font_color': '#9C6500'})

    worksheet.conditional_format('C2:C1048576', {'type':'formula',
                                       'criteria':'=B2<>C2',
                                       'format':orange_format})

    workbook.close()
```

I have two types of excels data as below

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but are you asking how you can reuse your conditional format that currently works on column C to work on columns E, K and M as well? Honestly, the simplest solution would be to create a new condition for each column. It's easy to do in python using a loop.

Comment: @Dan. Thanks a lot for the reply. In each excel i have KeyColumns mentioned and rest of the columns will be having _SRC and _TGT. without providing the hardcoded cell information like to compare B with C , can i run in a loop or any other way so that it will compare automatically all the columns like BwithC , DwithE ...

Comment: yes, see my answer. If you want, you can create `columns_to_format` like this `string.ascii_letters[2:26:2].upper()` (`import string` first)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're asking how to make

```
worksheet.conditional_format('C2:C1048576', {'type':'formula',
                                   'criteria':'=B2<>C2',
                                   'format':orange_format})
```

reusable to other columns, then try something like this:

```
def get_previous_column(column):
    # if you're expecting to go above column `Z` then you'll need to improve this function
    return chr(ord(column) - 1)

def make_conditional_format(worksheet, col_src, col_tgt):
    column_range = f"{col_tgt}2:{col_tgt}1048576"
    worksheet.conditional_format(
        column_range, 
        {
            'type':'formula',
            'criteria':f'={col_src}2<>{col_tgt}2',
            'format':orange_format
         }
    )

columns_to_format = ['C', 'E', 'K', 'M']

for col_tgt in columns_to_format:
    col_src = get_previous_column(col_tgt)
    make_conditional_format(worksheet, col_src, col_tgt)
```

Comment: Thanks Dan. Actually my 2 screen shots are 2 different excels. I have different scenarios.  But i am trying to find a way wherever i have "_SRC" & _TGT" i want to compare those corresponding columns

Comment: @Arya I've updated the answer to accept srouce and target columns. Now all you need to do is write the logic to find the "_SRC" & _TGT" pairs

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot. I will try with multiple scenarios and if i have any doubt can i ask in this same page ?

Comment: Hi Dan. As you mentioned one point # if you're expecting to go above column `Z` then you'll need to improve this function --- how can i handle if it is greater then 'Z' like 'AA', 'AB' ....

Comment: @Arya A very quick google lead me to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23862195/1011724 no idea if it works.